# Is Musa a Montenegrin Muslim female name?

Tags: names

I was checking family records and found out that a great grandfather married a Musa. I know that Musa is a male name but the records are kept in Turkish although the great grandparents were of Bosniak origin (Montenegro), so there is a high possibility that the registry person recorded the name in a Turkified form or made a typo when they arrived in Anatolia (still Musa doesn't make sense as it is the equivalent of Moses in Turkish). The closest I came is that Musa might be Mojca, a hypocorism of Maria (or Miriam as she was likely a Muslim). Still no clue, I don't know Serbo-Croatian. What can that name in original be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm Ukrainian and my grandmother's name was *Марія* - Maria, and the endearment form of it everybody used was *Муся* [ˈmusʲa]. That can well be the case with your grandmother, too.